# Hc-05 ha dejado de funcionar en modo at

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

Estaba trabajando con mi antena hc-05 de la compañía sh y mientras estaba obteniendo los RSSI en modo AT de repente se bloqueó y ya no puedo acceder a su modo AT. ¿A qué puede deberse y cómo lo arreglo? Estoy usando arduino uno y mega 2500.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta. Se había cambiado solo el baud rate, por tanto hay que iniciar la antena de la segunda manera que te dice el manual -> dándole 1 lógico directamente a la patilla EN. En el código al iniciar los seriales hay que ponerlos a 38400 y el terminal de arduino también. Una vez hecho eso ya te deja acceder a los comandos AT y ponerlo de vuelta a 9600 baudios.